# Why can't I declare a string in a class?

Tags: java, string, declare

```
public class Account {

    public int pin;
    public int accountnumber;
    public string accounttype;
    public double balance;
}
```

It tells me string cannot be resolved as a type.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, you will probably benefit from learning how to use an IDE for Java, this is the kind of stuff which the IDE can do you... You should try Eclipse, or NetBeans.... in Eclipse if you start typing the name of a class and type ctrl+space, Eclipse will suggest you the correct class names with the correct spelling... I am also going to assume that you are very new with Java.. I would recommend you the Head first Java... Great book for begginers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's `String` with a capital S

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
public String accounttype;
```

The others (`int`, `double`) are so called primitive data types where `String` is like `Account` "just another class".
 `int` has an  "equivalent" (yeah, I know) (`Integer`), that is like `String`

Answer (score 1):

String is not a primitive type.  In Java, objects/classes naming convention would have the first letter capitalized.

You know it is an object because it has methods and it is basically an array of characters.

Also you should declare most Class member variables as private (or protected) unless there is a specific reason you need to make it public.